# How to receive a parameter variable on a Ansible YAML file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to automate the installation of an Oracle RPatch file on a node computer with Ansible. The problem here is that I need to keep passing the patch ID, through Ansible, manually. Is there any way to pass that patch id as a parameter?
Thanks for your time.
Here is the sample of the code I am writing, so that you identify better what I am trying to substitute.

```
---
- hosts: web #group of hosts on host file
  remote_user: client
  become: yes #become super SU
  tasks:
    - name: Test Host Connection
      ping:
    - name: Copy Opatch zipfile to the Target Oracle_home
      copy: 
        src: #substitute for the oracle orpatch file
        dest: /tmp
    - name: Upgrade Rpatch
      shell: unzip -o /tmp/p6880880_112000_Linux-x86-64.zip -d $ORACLE_HOME #default is /u01/oracle/11204
      register: unzip
    - name: Define Retail Home Path
      shell: export RETAIL_HOME = </u01/app/rms>
    - name: Move to Retail_Home Directory
      shell: cd $RETAIL_HOME
    - name: execute rpatch to analyse the Patch
      shell: orpatch analyze -s /tmp/patch_id #define here the patch__id
    - name: ORPatch Apply
      shell: orpatch apply
    - name: List the Inventory
      shell: orpatch lsinventory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are playbook variables. I would suggest reading https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html as it will familiarize yourself with different ways of using variables. But I will show one way to pass it on the command line.

The following example makes your patch_id a templated variable. It also runs it through the `mandatory` filter making it required (playbook will fail early if it is not set).

```
---
- hosts: web #group of hosts on host file
  remote_user: client
  become: yes #become super SU
  tasks:
    - name: Test Host Connection
      ping:
    - name: Copy Opatch zipfile to the Target Oracle_home
      copy: 
        src: #substitute for the oracle orpatch file
        dest: /tmp
    - name: Upgrade Rpatch
      shell: unzip -o /tmp/p6880880_112000_Linux-x86-64.zip -d $ORACLE_HOME #default is /u01/oracle/11204
      register: unzip
    - name: Define Retail Home Path
      shell: export RETAIL_HOME = </u01/app/rms>
    - name: Move to Retail_Home Directory
      shell: cd $RETAIL_HOME
    - name: execute rpatch to analyse the Patch
      shell: orpatch analyze -s /tmp/{{ patch_id | mandatory }}
    - name: ORPatch Apply
      shell: orpatch apply
    - name: List the Inventory
      shell: orpatch lsinventory
```

You would then set `patch_id` at runtime using `-e` like:

```
ansible-playbook -i myinventory -e patch_id=mypatchid myplaybook.yaml
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think CLI variable and value should be in double quotes. Isn't it?

Comment: that patch_Id=mypatchid should be between double quotes, right?